# WOPI implementation without MS-FSSHTTP/COBALT

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365, ms-wopi, fsshttp

We are trying to implement a WOPI host without using CobaltCore dll against our Office Web Apps server. (implement in Java).  All the information I found suggests that you have to implement MS-FSSHTTP in order to edit Word documents.

But, this is what I found on this page: [Integrating with Office Online](http://wopi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#integration-process)

> Integrating with Office Online is relatively simple. You just need to do some 
>   HTML and JavaScript work, and set up a few simple REST endpoints. If you are familiar with existing Office protocols, note that you don’t have to implement the [MS-FSSHTTP]: File Synchronization via SOAP over HTTP Protocol (Cobalt)

There is also a sample implementation [here](http://wopi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build_test_ship/code_samples.html)

But I cannot get this to work when hitting our Office Web Apps Server (the header X-WOPI-Override equals to COBALT for Word docs).

1. Does the information on that page only applies to scenarios where you are hitting Office Online?
2. Is there a setting I have to change on the Office Web Apps Server so that it behaves like Excel file editing?  On the CheckFileInfo, I tried setting SupportsCoauth=false and SupportsCobalt=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the document/page I referred to in my question is referring to the **Office Online Server**... which is a replacement of the **Office Web Apps Server**.

I downloaded the Preview of the Office Online Server [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49028)

When you compare the discovery.xml from both versions, the Word docx edit requirements are different:

```
Office Web Apps Server:
<action name="edit" ext="docx" requires="locks,cobalt,update"

Office Online Server:
<action name="edit" ext="docx" requires="locks,update"
```

I was able to implement Word Editing without referencing the Microsoft.CobaltCore.dll